# How to (politely) bump a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

Often, questions get asked, answers are provided (that won't work, either because of a poorly asked question, or misunderstanding helper, it doesn't matter which). Edits are made to the question -- but it's too late! The question has fallen low on the question lists by this time - it's out of date. It's clearly rude to start a new question, but there's new material to be uncovered! How can we "bump" a question when appropriate, (without creating an infuriating tug-a-war between over-anxious clickers)?

Answer (score -1):

I normally re-edit my question, summing up the point so far, and adding more information if appropriate.

Comment: but from what I recall, that doesn't move your question to the top of the recent list... which just promotes reposting a similar question and adds to the list of things users have to sift through when searching.